# can't encode single quote (&#39;) using django's render_to_string

Tags: django, unicode, quotes, render-to-string

i have a problem with django's render_to_string and encoding single quotes.

```
... = render_to_string('dummy.txt', {'request':request, 'text':text,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)))
```

why are only these quotes translated to '#39;' and all other special characters not?

Comment: Could you provide some input/ output? dummy.txt maynbe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Automatic escaping](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping).
Link now changed to https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping

Comment: The "current" link in this answer links to the original proposal for the autoescape tag. Here's the link to the actual documentation... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape

Answer (score 1):

To get your string in plain letters, you need to unescape it.
surround your variable in autoescape off template tag.
Something like this

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what Daniel replied already 10 years ago. ;)

Comment: Just in case if someone is looking for a quick copy paste solution. :-)